# JqGrid. onSelectRow - Pegar id do campo e passar com url

Tags: php, jquery, postgresql, jqgrid

Opa, eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
// jqGrid //
      $grid->('onSelectRow', "fnHistoricoPessoa");
// fim jqGrid//

// função para onSelectRow//

function fnHistoricoPessoa(){

var kwGrid = $("#kwGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

if(kwGrid != null)
{
    var ret = $("#kwGrid").jqGrid('getRowData',kwGrid);

    $("#grid_historico").setGridParam({url:"/admin/pessoas/listagem_historico.json?id_familia=1",page:1});
    $("#grid_historico").trigger("reloadGrid");


}

}
```

Com esse código eu faço no jqGrid a opção de quando selecionar uma linha, ele preencher um outro grid com as informações que eu quero e são: `id_familia = 1` só que esse 1, eu botei manual só testar o grid, ou seja ele busca no banco de dados o `id_familia = 1` e joga na tela, mas eu não quero que em todas as telas seja sempre o `id_familia = 1`, quero que seja o `id_familia = id da familia que o usuario está buscando`.

Como eu faço para recuperar o id que o usuário está pesquisando?

Comment: este é uma url que tem o id de um cara qualquer cadastrado:
http://localhost:8080/admin/pessoas/integrantes/3984
id_familia = 3984;

Comment: Você vai ter de atribuir o valor de um input a uma variável e passar essa variável pela URL.

Comment: eu tentei assim: 
var kwGrid = $("#kwGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
var ret = $("#kwGrid").jqGrid('getRowData',kwGrid);

$("#grid_historico").setGridParam({url:"/admin/pessoas/listagem_historico.json?id_familia="ret['id_familia']",page
:1});

é algo assim que tu se refere?

Comment: Seria algo como: `var grid = $("#kwGrid"); var columnInfo = grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow'); var ret = grid.jqGrid('getRowData', columnInfo); $("#grid_historico").jqGrid('setGridParam', {url: '/admin/pessoas/listagem_historico.json?id_familia=' + ret['id_familia'], page:1});`

Comment: Opa, cara eu testei aqui, mas ele nao me retorna nada no grid. Eu dei um alert pra testar no ret['id_familia'] e ele traz o id certo.

Comment: Então o que você pode fazer é guardar tudo numa *`String`* e fazer um *`alert`* com ela. Se a *`String`* aparecer do jeito que é esperado, mande pelo `setGridParam`.

Comment: consegui, obrigado pela ajuda. Respondi a minha pergunta (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consegui fazendo desse modo com a ajuda daqui:

```
function fnHistoricoPessoa(){

var kwGrid = $("#kwGrid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');

if(kwGrid != null)
{
    var ret = $("#kwGrid").jqGrid('getRowData',kwGrid);

    $("#grid_historico").setGridParam({url:"/admin/pessoas/listagem_historico.json?id_familia=" + ret['id_familia'], page:1});
    $("#grid_historico").trigger("reloadGrid");


}
```

}